# Force user to select address from google maps api autocomplete

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps

Ive got this distance calculator using google maps api, and im trying to have two autocomplete forms for the start and ending address.... it works perfectly, except i want to force the user to select from the drop down, and not allow them to continue if they dont.

heres the code

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  //draw the map
     var rendererOptions = {
      map: map,
  preserveViewport: false,
      suppressMarkers : true
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions)

   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


  var input = (document.getElementById('start'));
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  var input2 = (document.getElementById('end'));
  var searchBox2 = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input2);

  var markers = [];

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
     }

    markers = [];
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         icon: 'http://www.driveu.com/images/pmarker.png',
         title: place.name,
         position: place.geometry.location
      });

       markers.push(marker);
       bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
     }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.setZoom(15);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox2, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox2.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker2; marker2 = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker2.setMap(null);
    }

    markers = [];
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
     var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: 'http://www.driveu.com/images/markerlarge.png',
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker2);
      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.setZoom(15);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
     searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
 }

function calcRoute() {
   var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

    var calc_distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value; 
        var drivingDistanceMiles = calc_distance / 1609.344;
        var drivingDistanceMiles = Math.round(drivingDistanceMiles*100)/100;

        var drivingrate1 = Math.round((drivingDistanceMiles*3.00)+2.80);
        var drivingrate2 = Math.round(((drivingDistanceMiles*3.00)+2.80)*1.15);
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<div id="next_line" style="display:none"><div style=" margin-right:5%; width:45%; float:left;"><strong> distance:</strong><br/><div style="background:#333; padding:15px; font-size:22px; color:#bbb;">'+drivingDistanceMiles+' <span style="font-size:12px;"> miles </span></div></div><div style=" width:50%; float:left;"><strong> estimate:</strong><br/>   <div style="background:#333; padding:15px; font-size:22px; color:#bbb;">$'+drivingrate1+' <span style="font-size:12px;"> to </span> $'+drivingrate2+'</div></div></div>';
    }
 });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

heres a demo
http://driveu.com/index2.php

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

if you're using jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    if $('form input.map_select_box').val() == ''
       event.preventDefault();
    end
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: thanks, kinda confused how to implement that tho.... what variable does map_select_box correspond to?

Comment: let say you have `<select class="map_select_box"> ...` so by saying `$('select.map_select_box')` you are saying to jQuery I want  select element with class map_select_box. Or you can just do `$('form .map_select_box')`  any element with class map_select_box inside a form.

Comment: so my code that I posted in answer is saying: When whole document is loaded, Listen to submit of any form element and when that happens if the value of the form input with class map_select_box is blank don't send this form

Comment: ...but once again this will work only when you use jQuery JavaScript library http://jquery.com/ . I recommend to use it, makes your life easier :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First, get the value entered in the location input box
2. Get predictions with that value using AutocompleteService
3. Then check if location value matches the prediction, if the value doesn't match the predictions then it means the user has not selected the location from autocomplete dropdown

```
var displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
    let valid_location = false;
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(Invalid location);
        return;
    }

    predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {

        if( $("#location").val().replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase() == prediction.description.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase() ){
            valid_location = true;
        }

    });
    if(valid_location){
        alert(Valid location);
    }
    else{
        alert(Invalid location);
    }
  };
var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
service.getQueryPredictions({ input: $("#location").val() }, displaySuggestions);
```